# Magento Database query hogging resources

Tags: mysql, sql-server, magento

I have a magento store on version 1.8.1.0 hosted with siteground. I've been notified by their system administrator that my database queries are hogging up too much resoruces. Here are what they've sent me. I'm at a complete loss in how to tackle this issue, any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

1 Executed 9h 26m 48s ago for 16.454657 sec on Database --> DB_production 
Date: 2015-10-05 22:41:18 Query_time: 16.454657 Rows_examined: 349107: Rows_sent 1 Lock_time: 0.000301

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT e.entity_id) 
FROM report_event AS report_table_views 
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS e ON e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS at_visibility_default ON (at_visibility_default.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_visibility_default.attribute_id = '102') AND at_visibility_default.store_id = 0 
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS at_visibility ON (at_visibility.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_visibility.attribute_id = '102') AND (at_visibility.store_id = 4) 
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS at_status_default ON (at_status_default.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_status_default.attribute_id = '96') AND at_status_default.store_id = 0 
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS at_status ON (at_status.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_status.attribute_id = '96') AND (at_status.store_id = 4) 
WHERE (report_table_views.event_type_id = 1) AND (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) = '4') AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = 1);
```

2 Executed 9h 26m 48s ago for 16.381442 sec on Database --> DB_production 
Date: 2015-10-05 22:41:18 Query_time: 16.381442 Rows_examined: 349107: Rows_sent 1 Lock_time: 0.000517

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT e.entity_id) 
FROM report_event AS report_table_views 
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS e ON e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS at_visibility_default ON (at_visibility_default.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_visibility_default.attribute_id = '102') AND at_visibility_default.store_id = 0 
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS at_visibility ON (at_visibility.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_visibility.attribute_id = '102') AND (at_visibility.store_id = 4) 
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS at_status_default ON (at_status_default.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_status_default.attribute_id = '96') AND at_status_default.store_id = 0 
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS at_status ON (at_status.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_status.attribute_id = '96') AND (at_status.store_id = 4) 
WHERE (report_table_views.event_type_id = 1) AND (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) = '4') AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = 1);
```

=== TOP 10 of 1854 (total) Slow Queries for the past 24 hours ==========
[36;1m 1. Executed 13h 30m 41s ago for 9.566494 sec on Database --> [33;1mDB_production[0m [0m
[36mDate: 2015-10-06 21:35:51 Query_time: 9.566494 Rows_examined: 234795: Rows_sent 68398 Lock_time: 0.011157[0m

SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d` LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 4 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (1678, 1682, 1828, 1830, 1834, 1837, 1839, 1926, 1942, 1982, 1983, 1985, 1987, 1989, 2316, 2325, 3299, 1510, 2055, 2172, 2282, 2283, 2328, 2333, 1075, 1771, 1780, 1818, 1849, 1850, 1853, 2569, 2570, 2572, 2573, 2574, 2575, 2576, 2577, 2578, 2579, 2728)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('75', '76', '120')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_d` LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 4 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (1678, 1682, 1828, 1830, 1834, 1837, 1839, 1926, 1942, 1982, 1983, 1985, 1987, 1989, 2316, 2325, 3299, 1510, 2055, 2172, 2282, 2283, 2328, 2333, 1075, 1771, 1780, 1818, 1849, 1850, 1853,

====== I Truncated a lot of the entity ID for this post=======

3456, 3457, 3458, 3459, 3460, 3461, 3462, 3463, 3464, 3465, 3466, 3467, 3468, 2545, 2546, 2547, 2548, 2549, 2550, 2551, 2552, 2553, 2554, 2555, 2558, 2559, 2560, 2561, 2562, 2563, 2564, 2565, 2566, 2567, 2568, 2569, 2570, 2572, 2573, 2574, 2575, 2576, 2577, 2578, 2579, 2728)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('96', '122', '124', '126', '127', '128', '129', '132', '134')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0);

Comment: Do you have log cleaning enabled? There are a few tables that will grow to an enormous size if they aren't cleaned periodically. You should check your table sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is and i've already truncated the log tables, reindex, and cleared cache. My provider just notified me with another incident.

Comment: Database is about 300mb currently, with about 2-3k products

Answer (score 0):

I have the same with magento and Siteground. They block my site because there are slow queries, but resource usage is normal - CPU time and account executions are not over limitations ;/ They suggest me to upgrade plan to Cloud or Dedicated server. But at this time my site is not fully finish and there are no visitors and don't know why they block my site only for that there are slow queries ;/ i'm using GrowBig shared hosting at this time, and here are the queries:

"I carefully checked for you and I can see that there are still some slow queries. You can check the results from here:
Code:
I carefully checked for you and I can see that there are still some slow queries. You can check the results from here:
Code:
7. Executed 8h 38m 41s ago for 3.789867 sec on Database --> devakorp_mage878
Date: 2015-10-12 19:41:24 Query_time: 3.789867 Rows_examined: 101030: Rows_sent 173 Lock_time: 0.000547

### SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active`, IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) AS `include_in_menu`, `mg_core_url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `mg_catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id` = 1) INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu_default` ON (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND `at_include_in_menu_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `mg_catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu` ON (`at_include_in_menu`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`store_id` = 1) LEFT JOIN `mg_core_url_rewrite` ON (mg_core_url_rewrite.category_id=e.entity_id) AND (mg_core_url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND mg_core_url_rewrite.product_id IS NULL AND mg_core_url_rewrite.store_id='1' AND id_path LIKE 'category/%') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (`e`.`entity_id` IN('3', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '185', '186', '187', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207', '208', '209', '210', '211', '212', '213', '216', '217', '218', '27', '151', '152', '28', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '29', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '30', '31', '16', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '14', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '108', '109', '110', '111', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '38', '199', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '17', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '6', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '198', '18', '197', '214', '215', '200', '230', '231', '234', '235', '236', '237', '232', '233')) AND (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) = '1');

8. Executed 3h 18m 25s ago for 3.449602 sec on Database --> devakorp_mage878
   Date: 2015-10-13 01:01:40 Query_time: 3.449602 Rows_examined: 93735: Rows_sent 0 Lock_time: 0.000094

   ### INSERT INTO `mg_catalog_product_index_eav` (`entity_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `value`) SELECT `mg_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`entity_id`, `mg_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`attribute_id`, `mg_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`store_id`, `mg_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`value` FROM `mg_catalog_product_index_eav_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`);
9. Executed 8h 41m 52s ago for 3.428078 sec on Database --> devakorp_mage878
   Date: 2015-10-12 19:38:13 Query_time: 3.428078 Rows_examined: 0: Rows_sent 0 Lock_time: 0.000000

   ### commit;
10. Executed 1h 50m 14s ago for 3.172525 sec on Database --> devakorp_mage878
    Date: 2015-10-13 02:29:51 Query_time: 3.172525 Rows_examined: 0: Rows_sent 0 Lock_time: 0.003677
    DELETE FROM `mg_catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;

Answer (score 0):

i have changed host to another. in siteground i paid 14e pro month, now i pay 20e, i have VPS and two magento shop with 10 000 SKU and resources are minimal and site is more faster. i am disapointed with siteground and surprised with new hosting www.netdc.pl (polish hosting).